# Which site for a work Visa question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I wonder about how other people handle working remotely. For instance, managing a network.
What labor law, in which country applies, when working internationally.

BUT I am not sure where to ask that.
I figured on Stack Overflow I will get dinged as it is not about programming, and it isn't a Super User question, but I am sure other people might have some ideas.

Comment: Slightly related: Site *[Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour)* often has questions about visas, including work-related visas, like [H-1B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa) (United States). 10,266 questions [are tagged with 'visas'](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas). 141 questions [are tagged with 'h1b-visas'](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas).

Comment: This is an old question! The law changes about every three months at the moment. (2023)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's really good for any site on the Trilogy, as it's more legal-related than tech-related.

Consider:

- It's definitely not programming-related, although workers on visas may be programmers. Thus, it clearly does not belong on StackOverflow.
- It's definitely not server administration-related, although workers on visas may be sysadmins. Thus, it clearly does not belong on ServerFault.
- It's not generally computer-related, although workers on visas are probably using computers. Thus, it clearly does not belong on SuperUser.

Thus, while it's a good and valid question to ask *somewhere*, the Trilogy sites are probably not the best place to go. Indeed, because laws are different everywhere in the world, and the subject here is a particularly tricky one because it often involves multinational law, I would personally be highly skeptical of *any* advice you get *anywhere* on the Internet.

Frankly, I'd recommend consulting an attorney well-versed with international labor laws and regulations, and work visas in particular.

Comment: **Agreed.** I've worked in four countries under various arrangements (like working in the UK for USD) and, in hindsight, know that some of it was down right dodgy. You can get stiffed by the employer, have unexpected tax liabilities, not be eligible for social insurances (workplace injury, unemployment), etc. Time to *"lawyer up"*, it is worth the cost. And don't take your employer's word for it regarding your local laws or their own.

Comment: Thank You both. I know you are right. I have someone asking me to occasionally do some tasks on servers not in the US and since I will be sitting in the US, I was wondering how it will be construed.
I guess this is similar to tech support in India talking to someone not in India. Where is the work happening? I am independent so I guess I have to find out.

Comment: Well, that sounds very much like independent contract work, which is legally different than employment.  You'll want to talk to a tax adviser more than a labor law person.  Note many employers (like your current full time gig) don't allow their employees to take on extra work.  Something to think about.